# Gather input from user while ongoing twilio conference call

Tags: java, spring-boot, twilio, twilio-api

In my app i am making twilio conference call, while ongoing conference call at any time when callee press * key i want to announce some options and gather one input from user(callee).

Is it possible ? and How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First, set the [`hangupOnStar` attribute on the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#attributes-hangup-on-star) for your `<Conference>` to `true`. Then set the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#attributes-action) to a URL that returns a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) and [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say) to read out the options. Once you have dealt with the response to the `<Gather>` redirect the caller back into the `<Conference>`.

Comment: In my case i don't want to hangup on star (*) key pressed because i have written another code segment on hangup...is it possible to take input on * key pressed without hangup

Comment: It is not. It's not possible to bring up options within a `<Conference>` so you need to hangup in order to route to different TwiML.

Comment: Is it possible that if any participant press # then only disconnect that participant from conference.

Comment: No, you can only do that with `*` (which is why the attribute is called `hangupOnStar`).

Comment: @philnash If I close the call via REST by setting the status = completed, will it fire the action attribute triggering the rest of the flow? In my case I don't expect the user to press "*" and hangup in order to run the Q&A.

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal I believe so, but I recommend you test in order to see what happens.

Comment: Hi @philnash In our case on outgoing call, we create conference room first and add the participant. that working now. but if the call initiator press 3 (any number) we need to gather to go to specific IVR menu. How can I do that.. ? Thank you..

Comment: In a Twilio conference you can use the [`hangupOnStar` attribute on the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#hanguponstar) to remove a caller from the conference and have them visit an IVR with options. Once they have selected the option they want, you can then use TwiML to direct them back into the conference. You can't do this with numbers though, only the `*` key.